# Remove one last input field on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of checkbox I want to hide one last input field. I have tried `prev` and `closest` but it is not working. There are few other set of same kind of input fields so I just want to target on last input field. So on click of this checkbox I want to hide last input field `job_to_date[]`. Below is my code.

```js
jQuery('input[name^="currently_work_here"]').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
    jQuery(this).prev('.job_to_date').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="text" name="job_from_date[]" value="" placeholder="From" class="job_from_date">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="text" name="job_to_date[]" value="" placeholder="To" class="job_to_date">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input type="checkbox" name="currently_work_here[]" class="resume_builder_input input_checkbox"> I currently work here
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/benmajor/n1myje36/?

Comment: Your code works fine (as you can see in the snippet I added to the question). Is the issue that the field does not re-appear when you uncheck the box?

Comment: @Awan _No these are not hiding_. By "these" do you mean both of the `input` fields? If so, please reconstruct your question

Comment: Sorry I mean just one last input field with class name of job_to_date

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can see above code is not working now. Sorry I missed external divs because I thought these could not make any difference. I am new with coding so forgive me and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your revised HTML you need to use `.parent().prev().find('.job_to_date')` to locate the element you want to remove:

```js
jQuery('input[name^="currently_work_here"]').change(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('.job_to_date').remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="job_from_date[]" value="" placeholder="From" class="job_from_date">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="job_to_date[]" value="" placeholder="To" class="job_to_date">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input type="checkbox" name="currently_work_here[]" class="resume_builder_input input_checkbox"> I currently work here
</div>
```

`.prev()` alone won't work based on your structure. You need to go up a level via `.parent()`, then to the previous div with `.prev()`, finally finding the one to remove with `.find('.job_to_date')`

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and time.